# Module not found error on npm package in react app but working on codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, datatable

I was trying to use a react component package for displaying CSV in a data table and found [active-table-react](https://activetable.io/docs/examples). I have a React application created using CRA and typescript template where I added the npm package but after importing the component and running `npm start` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/active-table/dist/activeTable.js 32:0-54
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './activeTableStyle' in '/home/user/Projects/react-table-demo/node_modules/active-table/dist'
Did you mean 'activeTableStyle.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './activeTableStyle' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

I have tried using different versions of node and react but to no avail. However, the example sandbox [shown in the docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/active-table-react-cstm7k?file=/src/App.tsx) is working fine although I have the same exact configuration. Here's my code for comparison.

```
// App.tsx

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { ActiveTable } from 'active-table-react';

function App() {
  const content = [
    ["Planet", "Diameter", "Mass"],
    ["Earth", 12756, 5.97],
    ["Mars", 6792, 0.642]
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ActiveTable
        content={content}
        headerStyles={{ default: { backgroundColor: "#d6d6d630" } }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I missing here? Any kind of help would be appreciated.
[Active table documentation](https://activetable.io/docs/introduction)
[Active table source](https://github.com/OvidijusParsiunas/active-table)

Comment: could you add **webpack.config.js** ?

Answer (score 0):

in your **webpack.config.js** in  `rules`  add :

```
{
  test: /\.m?js/,
  resolve: {
    fullySpecified: false
  }
}
```

Comment: I know webpack solves it but why does it work on codesandbox instead? I don't see any webpack config there

Comment: if you go to codesandbox and **sandbox info** you'll see that **Environment** it is using **create-react-app** . click it to see it in github  thensearch for **webpack.config.js** the first one you'll find thes configuration it's just a little different not the same as my answer

Comment: you're not getting the same behaviour as vscode probabley because it different **cra** than the one you're using